# Specifying interface as parameter to javax.inject.Provider<IsAnInterface>

Tags: java, spring, code-injection

I have a class GList which implements the interface IQList.

I have a class Qurious in which I need a Provider to provide prototypes of GList. (Besides annotating GList scope as prototype).

However, I do not want Qurious to be aware of the existence of GList. Therefore, in Qurious, I have a declaration

```
Provider<IQList> qlistProvider.
```

What do I have to do with either GList or applicationContext, so that Spring will instantiate GList to satisfy

```
Provider<IQList>
```

?

I am trying to avoid defining a factory.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly:
Instantiatin Spring bean of type Provider in spring configuration
and annotating your `Provider<IQList> qlistProvider.` as @Autowired should be enough.

Or do you want Spring framework to guess that you will need a particular type of object instance and do it for you? I don't think that it can

Comment: I was hoping that spring would search for implementation of IQList that has bean annotated as a component or bean.

Comment: AFAIR you have to list all beans that you want to instantiate and then Spring will inject them for you. (Just a thought) It may have a problem with auto instantiation because it injects by matching name or type and `Provider<IQList>` will not match `Provider<IQListImpl>`